# How to add pre-required softwares at the time of making installer in .net?

Tags: .net

What I want to do is, I want to add .net framework with my setup file that will install before my application installation.

Answer (score 1):

Amit, this is easy, just right click on your project in Visual Studio, properties... there is a tab where you can specify exactly the project pre-requisites.

Comment: thanx. i did it but when i try to install setup file it do not find the .net framework which i included in this setup because i have assigned its location in 'c:/program file/soft' and installing from desktop. how can i fix this. i want to install it from any where.. plz help.